Want a recylerview to start from bottom to top onCreation of activity and scroll on bottom again when new item added
I've an activity in my Android App named as ChatActivity. Here is the xml layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    tools:context=".ui.home.ui.chat.ChatActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        app:navigationIconTint="@color/black"
        app:title="@string/chat"
        app:titleCentered="true" >
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dummy_user"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvMessages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_95sdp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_message_sent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tiMessage"
        style="@style/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_35sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:errorEnabled="false"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/_200sdp"
            android:autofillHints="name"
            android:hint="@string/message"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSend"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_message"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tiMessage"
        app:tint="@color/blue" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

When I open the textInput field, the layout does not adapt to it, it shows only keyboard to open but when i type in keyboard it does gets typed in text input layout, but while typiing the user cannot see the text input layout with out closing the keyboard
+
The recyclerview start scroll from top to bottom but i want t to be like a chat, bottom to top. And on new message added it does scroll to bottom but on the last iitem of the exsiting list not on the new item.
I've tried using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" for keyboard and
private fun scrollToBottom() {
        binding.rvMessages.scrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount -1)
    }

for recylerview.
Any suggestions for optimizing the code / for betterment is welcome. My activity code is:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ChatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityChatBinding
    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var adapter: ChatAdapter
    private var currentUserId: Int = 0
    private var otherUserId: Int = 0
    private lateinit var conversationId: String
    private var convoId = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        binding = ActivityChatBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
        binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() }

        val userDetails = intent.getParcelableExtra<ConnectionDetailDTO>("USER_DETAILS")
        val currentUser = Paper.book().read<User>(Constant.k_user)

        currentUserId = currentUser?.id!!
        otherUserId = userDetails?.id!!

        binding.toolbar.title = userDetails.name
        Glide.with(this).load(userDetails.profileUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_dummy_user).into(binding.ivProfile)
        binding.ivProfile.setOnClickListener{showProfile()}

        adapter = ChatAdapter(currentUserId)
        binding.rvMessages.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.rvMessages.adapter = adapter
        scrollToBottom()

        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val reference = database.getReference("Conversations")

        reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val messages = mutableListOf<Message>()
                for (conversationSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val conversationIdParts = conversationSnapshot.key?.split("_")
                    if (conversationIdParts?.size == 3) {
                        val firstUserId = conversationIdParts[1]
                        val secondUserId = conversationIdParts[2]
                        convoId = "conversation_${firstUserId}_${secondUserId}"

                        if (firstUserId == currentUserId.toString() && secondUserId == otherUserId.toString()
                            || firstUserId == otherUserId.toString() && secondUserId == currentUserId.toString()) {
                            val conversationMessages = mutableListOf<Message>()
                            for (messageSnapshot in conversationSnapshot.child("messages").children) {
                                val content = messageSnapshot.child("content").value.toString()
                                val date = messageSnapshot.child("date").value.toString()
                                val messageId = messageSnapshot?.child("id")?.value.toString()
                                val isRead = messageSnapshot.child("isRead").value as? Boolean ?: false
                                val name = messageSnapshot.child("name").value.toString()
                                val senderEmail = messageSnapshot.child("senderEmail").value.toString()
                                val type = messageSnapshot.child("type").value.toString()

                                val message = Message(content, date, messageId, isRead, name, senderEmail, type)
                                conversationMessages.add(message)
                                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: $message")
                            }
                            messages.addAll(conversationMessages)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: $messages")
                adapter.updateMessages(messages)
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                println("Error: ${databaseError.message}")
            }
        })
        binding.ivSend.setOnClickListener {
            val messageText = binding.tiMessage.editText?.text.toString().trim()

            if (messageText.isNotEmpty()) {
                val conversationId1 = "conversation_${currentUserId}_${otherUserId}"
                val conversationId2 = "conversation_${otherUserId}_${currentUserId}"
                reference.child(conversationId1).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        val data = task.result?.value
                        val conversationId = if (data != null) {
                            conversationId1
                        } else {
                            conversationId2
                        }
                        val messageReference =
                            reference.child(conversationId).child("messages").push()
                        val message = Message(
                            content = messageText,
                            date = SimpleDateFormat(
                                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                Locale.getDefault()
                            ).format(Date()),
                            id = messageReference.key!!,
                            isRead = false,
                            name = currentUser?.name ?: "",
                            senderEmail = currentUserId.toString(),
                            type = "text"
                        )
                        messageReference.setValue(message)
                        binding.tiMessage.editText?.setText("")
                        scrollToBottom()
                    }
                }

                addUser(currentUserId.toString())
            }
        }
}

    private fun scrollToBottom() {
        binding.rvMessages.scrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount -1)
    }
}

I tried solutions for recycler view from StackOverFLow & Chat GPT


The recyclerview start scroll from top to bottom but i want t to be
like a chat, bottom to top. And on new message added it does scroll to
bottom but on the last iitem of the exsiting list not on the new item.
I've tried using..

The reason the recyclerView starts from the top and does not scroll to the bottom on a new item is because you are calling scrollToBottom() before adding items to the adapter.
Remove scrollToBottom() that is in binding.ivSend.setOnClickListener{} and add it below adapter.updateMessages(messages)
Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: $messages")
adapter.updateMessages(messages)
scrollToBottom()

This way the recyclerview will scroll down when items are first loaded from the database and when a new item is added.
For easier code readability i advice you to sort your code into method instead of putting everything in override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {} as such.
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    enableEdgeToEdge()
    binding = ActivityChatBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
        val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
        insets
    }


    setArgs()
    setupUI()
    setupDatabase()
    setupListeners()

}

private fun setArgs(){
    userDetails = intent.getParcelableExtra<ConnectionDetailDTO>("USER_DETAILS")
    currentUser = Paper.book().read<User>(Constant.k_user)
}

private fun setupUI(){
    //toolbar
    binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() }

    binding.toolbar.title = userDetails.name
    Glide.with(this).load(userDetails.profileUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_dummy_user).into(binding.ivProfile)
    binding.ivProfile.setOnClickListener{showProfile()}

    //recycler view
    adapter = ChatAdapter(currentUser.id)
    binding.rvMessages.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    binding.rvMessages.adapter = adapter
}

private fun setupDatabase(){
     database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
     reference = database.getReference("Conversations")
}

private fun setupListeners(){
    reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val messages = mutableListOf<Message>()
            for (conversationSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                val conversationIdParts = conversationSnapshot.key?.split("_")
                if (conversationIdParts?.size == 3) {
                    val firstUserId = conversationIdParts[1]
                    val secondUserId = conversationIdParts[2]
                    convoId = "conversation_${firstUserId}_${secondUserId}"

                    if (firstUserId == currentUser.id.toString() && secondUserId == currentUser.id.toString()
                        || firstUserId == userDetails.id.toString() && secondUserId == currentUser.id.toString()) {
                        val conversationMessages = mutableListOf<Message>()
                        for (messageSnapshot in conversationSnapshot.child("messages").children) {
                            val content = messageSnapshot.child("content").value.toString()
                            val date = messageSnapshot.child("date").value.toString()
                            val messageId = messageSnapshot?.child("id")?.value.toString()
                            val isRead = messageSnapshot.child("isRead").value as? Boolean ?: false
                            val name = messageSnapshot.child("name").value.toString()
                            val senderEmail = messageSnapshot.child("senderEmail").value.toString()
                            val type = messageSnapshot.child("type").value.toString()

                            val message = Message(content, date, messageId, isRead, name, senderEmail, type)
                            conversationMessages.add(message)
                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: $message")
                        }
                        messages.addAll(conversationMessages)
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: $messages")
            adapter.updateMessages(messages)
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            println("Error: ${databaseError.message}")
        }
    })


    binding.ivSend.setOnClickListener {
        val messageText = binding.tiMessage.editText?.text.toString().trim()

        if (messageText.isNotEmpty()) {
            val conversationId1 = "conversation_${currentUser.id}_${userDetails.id}"
            val conversationId2 = "conversation_${userDetails.id}_${currentUser.id}"
            reference.child(conversationId1).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val data = task.result?.value
                    val conversationId = if (data != null) {
                        conversationId1
                    } else {
                        conversationId2
                    }
                    val messageReference =
                        reference.child(conversationId).child("messages").push()
                    val message = Message(
                        content = messageText,
                        date = SimpleDateFormat(
                            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                            Locale.getDefault()
                        ).format(Date()),
                        id = messageReference.key!!,
                        isRead = false,
                        name = currentUser?.name ?: "",
                        senderEmail = currentUser.id.toString(),
                        type = "text"
                    )
                    messageReference.setValue(message)
                    binding.tiMessage.editText?.setText("")
                    scrollToBottom()
                }
            }

            addUser(currentUser.id.toString())
        }
    }
}

Lastly i would advice you to read up on MVVM design pattern for more code structure.
